# 12-th cyclotomic polynomial evaluated at p

Tags: elliptic-curves, cyclotomic-polynomials

I just want to check a small thesis of a paper [1]. It is written in the proof of Lemma 4. The author points out, that $\Phi_{12}(p)=p^4-p^2+1$. I wrote a small sageworksheet for verify this, but it gave me something different, so I'm probably wrong. In sage you can calculate through

```
from sage.rings.polynomial.cyclotomic import cyclotomic_coeffs
c=cyclotomic_coeffs(12)
R = GF(2^(12))['x']
Phi(x)=R(c)
```

the 12-th cyclotomic polynomial ofer $GF(2^{12})$. Now you can evaluate at p:

```
var('p');
Phi(p)
```

and it returns $p^4 + p^2 + 1$. 
Since the characteristic of R is 2, isn't $p^2 = -p^2$? Or how do I get the statement?

[1] http://eprint.iacr.org/2005/133

Comment: uhm..a fast and nice answere.(@wikipedia link) But why does sage go "wrong"?

Comment: Are you working modulo $2$ ? that would explain the change in sign.

Comment: It's not wrong.  The cyclotomic polynomials, by definition, are polynomials over the integers.  If you choose to map them into polynomials over a field of characteristic $2$, then $-x^2 = x^2$.

Comment: So were my thoughts, too. Because if I add $x^2+x^2$ over $GF(2^n)$, then it vanishes. Therefore it has to be $x^2 = -x^2$. But I think it is curious.